# Problem on sending hidden value from a form

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I'm creating a forum on Laravel that contain sections, threads and comments. 
Users can create threads on sections, and comments on threads.
My problem is when user is creating a thread on a section I'm sending the section ID via hidden input value and if user edit that value he can post in other section.

What would be the best practice to do that? Or is there any way to get that id from controller or something like that? thanks

Comment: And what is wrong if user changes section? He does not have rights to post in this section? If so - then check user's rights before adding new thread and react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden form input values cannot be used to really hide something from the user. They are only hiding the value visually.

If a user is only allowed to edit their own thread, then you should check this in two places:

1. When the user enters the editor for that thread.
2. When the user submits an edit for that thread.

The check is simple. The user should be logged in, so in the session for that user you have stored the user id. In your database row for a threat you have also stored who wrote that thread. This is likely to be the user id. So you can compare those two values: They should match.

Comment: In my forum, there is no users, everyone is anonymous, so I have no users ID, everyone can post in all threads except for the closed ones or admin messages, maybe it's not a problem if an user edit where he wants to post since he is allowed to post in all sections?

Comment: Well, if that's what you want, yeah, let people post everywhere, but a visitor should be able to edit their own posts. Just imagine if you couldn't correct anything on Stack Overflow, that would be terrible. Luckily, you can still use sessions, even if no login is required. Just assign a session to a visitor on their first visit and as long the session cookie is not deleted they can edit their own posts.